# Why is this setTimeout not working & related question inside

Tags: javascript, html, settimeout

I have this script on a page of mine and the setTimeout function never fires. It's just an alert right now but i'm just testing it out. I'm doing a meta refresh on the page just after it if that's any clue, but i've also given that a 10 sec delay so the page isn't refreshed before it's supposed to trigger.

Also, the related question: If I run a javascript with a delay of, say, 10 seconds (with setTimeout) and in that javascript I try to modify a design element that's not on the page when the setTimeout is declared but will be by the time the script is fired. Will it work?

```
<script language=javascript>

var xmlhttp_get_memento;    
function loop_alerte(){
    setTimeout( function() {
        alert("timeout");
    }, 5000);
    xmlhttp_get_memento = new XMLHttpRequest();
    if (xmlhttp_get_memento==null)
    {
        alert ("Browser does not support HTTP Request (1)");
        return;
    }   
    var url="crm/ajax/get_mementos.php";
    url=url+"?sid="+Math.random();
    xmlhttp_get_memento.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp_get_memento.readyState == 4) {  
            alert(xmlhttp_get_memento.responseText);                                        
            schimbare_tip_cursor("default");
        }
        else{
            schimbare_tip_cursor("progress");
        }
    };

xmlhttp_get_memento.open("GET",url,true);
xmlhttp_get_memento.send(null);
}

loop_alerte();
</script>';
```

Comment: You should split this into separate questions.

Comment: Would be nice to pick an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `setTimeout` looks good, so there's probably something else that's wrong. Have you tried using a javascript debugger to see if you get any errors?

As for your second question, yes, that shouldn't be any problem, as the anonymous function inside the setTimout won't be evaluated until it runs. Live sample here: http://jsbin.com/afonup/2/edit Both with and without jQuery.

Comment: I've since gotten it to work. The problems where the alert not being set as the return of the anonymous function and i had a meta refresh just after the javascript that that was reloading the page, preventing the alert from displaying. Also, thanks for the sample, helped me understand setTimeout better

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your setTimeout, you will need to debug further
As for your second question -- the function will run, but whatever it is you were trying to do will not work.

Comment: That's not right, the function will run fine, and whatever he's trying to do will work, even if the element doesn't exist when the setTimeout is reached, because the function won't be evaluated until later. Look at my answer and code sample.

Comment: my website is a combination of ajax loaded elements and what i'm trying to do is start the timeout before a section is loaded and run the actual function after it's loaded to modify an element in it.

Answer (score 0):

Cleaning up your code would be a nice start. I can imagine a browser doesn't understand the tag `<script language=javascript>`. I suggest to use `<script type="text/javascript">` and if you're lucky, your javascript might work!

Comment: well, the javascript does work, there's just something stopping the alert in the setTimeout from showing. But thanks for your remark anyway.